# Is there a way to hide the header of the homepage component

Tags: jquery, home-page-component

I have a homepage component which displays an Vf page in an iframe.
I need a way to somehow hide the header of the component. I mean the name of the component and not the VF page header

Any thoughts on how it can be done?

Update :

Looks like my question was misunderstood. I just want the VF page to display without the homepage component header. if the component i created was [image]

Then on the home page i would get name RefereralSchedule displayed as heading after which my Vf page would be displayed. I want to somehow hide the heading ReferralSchedule heading and just display the VF page

Comment: Have you tried `showHeader="false"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can add the below script in you component

```
<script src="/resource/jQuery"></script>
<script>
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
//on document ready
j$(function(){
j$("h2.brandPrimaryFgr").each(function(){
     //add your component name here
    if(j$(this).text() == 'your component name'){
        j$(this).parent("div").hide();
    }
});
});
</script>
//your vf iframe here
<iframe src="/apex/yourvfpage"></iframe>
```

Comment: awesome.. that worked

Answer (score 0):

In the Visualforce Page add the attribute `showheader="false"` on the [`<apex:page>`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) element.

```
<apex:page showheader="false">
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, i have updated the question